# SwiftUI, unique stepper for items in a list view

Tags: swiftui

I'm wanting to display a list of an array fetched from an NSManagedObject.
Then in that list have a stepper for each item that will eventually same the incremented amount to a property of the NSManagedObject.

My code so far:

```
struct ExtraIncomeAdviceView: View {

    var incomes:FetchedResults<Income>
    var savingsGoals:FetchedResults<SavingsGoal>
    var presentationModeAddIncomeView: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationModeAdvice: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var increment:Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            Text("So you got an extra £\(String(format: "%0.2f",getLatestExtraIncome()))?").font(.headline)
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text("For your goals, set aside:").font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Spacer()
                }
                ForEach(self.savingsGoals) { goal in

                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Stepper("Add to \(goal.name!): \(goal.progressAmount!)", onIncrement: {
                            self.increment += 1
                            print("Adding to age")
                        }, onDecrement: {
                            self.increment -= 1
                            print("Subtracting from age")
                        })

                    }

                }

            }.padding()
                .padding(.vertical, 40)
            Button(action:  {


                self.presentationModeAdvice.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                self.presentationModeAddIncomeView.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Got it!")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)

                    .padding(15)
                    .background(Color .orange)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
            }

        }.padding()
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that every goal thats displayed in the ForEach reads and writes to the same variable. I'm stuck on how to somehow dynamically create new variables to read and write to for each item in the array.

Comment: i don't get it...what's your problem? do you get an error? Why shouldn't you be allowed to increase you ManagedObject in s´Stepper -> the stepper executes not when you show the list, but when the user taps on the stepper and then the list will be updated, which is ok...

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would make a custom view struct that is called within the `ForEach` named `GoalRow()` or something applicable that contains the your HStack, Stepper, and local increment variable. Then, you can handle the stepped value appropriately within the `GoalRow()` struct and clean up your code a bit.

```
ForEach(self.savingsGoals) { goal in
    GoalRow(goal: goal)
}
```

and then within `GoalRow`:

```
struct GoalRow: View {

    var goal: YourObject
    @State private var increment: Int = 0

    var body: some View {

            HStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {

                Stepper("Add to \(goal.name!): \(goal.progressAmount!)", onIncrement: {
                    self.increment += 1
                    // edit your proposed progress amount here
                    print("Adding to age")
                }, onDecrement: {
                    self.increment -= 1
                    // edit your proposed progress amount here
                    print("Subtracting from age")
                })
            }
```

Apple mentioned this in their tutorial. See the example for `LandmarkRow` in this tutorial [Building Lists and Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation)